# Read CSV file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to read a *.csv* file using *PowerShell*.

The file I am using looks like this one:

[image: This is the file I am using]

```
Application;Email
ApplicationName 1;random@address.com
ApplicationName 2;another@email.com
```

I searched on Internet some ways to read a *.csv* file with *PowerShell*, and I found this one which seems pretty simple and clear:

```
$csvfile = Import-CSV -Path "$ScriptDir\SpecificApp.csv"
Foreach ($el in $csvfile) {
    Write-Host $el.Email
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't display anything, and when I try to change the line `Write-Host $el.Email` with `Write-Host $el` I get this:

`@{Application;Email=ApplicationName 1;random@address.com}
 @{Application;Email=ApplicationName 2;another@email.com}`

I know I could retrieve the data with some `.split()`, but I would like to understand **how I can get those data *normally***

Comment: Can you please post the actual file contents (at least a few lines without sensitive data) and not an Excel(?) screenshot?

Comment: Just added down below the screenshot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens, as you are using semicolon `;` as field separator. Per default,  [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1) expects a comma `,`. Thus there is just one column named `Application;Email` instead of two `Application` and `Email`

```
$csvfile

Application;Email
-----------------
ApplicationName 1;random@address.com
ApplicationName 2;another@email.com
```

You can even refer to the unexpected column name by using double quotes (as colon is statement separator character):

```
$csvfile | % {$_."Application;Email"}
ApplicationName 1;random@address.com
ApplicationName 2;another@email.com
```

To get expected results, use `-Delimeter` parameter like so,

```
$csvfile = Import-CSV -Path C:\temp\ps.csv -Delimiter ";"
$csvfile

Application       Email
-----------       -----
ApplicationName 1 random@address.com
ApplicationName 2 another@email.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this fixed my problem !